# Change style of all elements of a class via prototype javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, prototypejs

This is probably really simple, but the prototype docs on the $$(function) really suck. What do I DO with all the items once the function gives them to me?

First I tried:

```
$$('div.category').style.height = 400 +"px";
```

Then:

```
$$('div.category').each(.style.height = 400 +"px");
```

Finally:

```
for (x in $$('div.category'))
{
    x.style.height = 400 +"px";
}
```

None of them are working. Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$$('div.category').each(function(d){
    d.style.height = '400px';
});
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$$('div.category').invoke('setStyle', { height: '400px' });
```

Read more on [invoke](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/enumerable/invoke).